# How can I search all records from all tables in a database for dates that contain the current month?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database named `db_contacts`, and it contains tables for each account to store their individual contacts. Each table is formatted the same way, with one date column being called `birthday`.

What I want to be able to do is search every record from every table in `db_contacts` for the dates whose month is equal to the current month.
Is there a way to do this using only one query, or will I have to query each table separately? I'm really at a loss for how to do this.

I was thinking something like this, but this doesn't work at all:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "foo", "bar");

$month = date("m");

$db = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'birthday'");
$db->execute();

foreach ($db as $table) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($table); $i++) {
        $db = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT birthday FROM $table[$i] WHERE MONTH('birthday') = $month;");
        $db->execute();

        foreach ($db as $row) {
            echo $row[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm inclined to think you can eliminate the FOR ($1 = . . . loop and just do your second select once on each table as FOREACH ($db . . . steps through your first result. And maybe not redefine $db inside the FOREACH loop.

Comment: Should I ask why you have a different table for each account? You can probably fix this code, but it will be much more efficient to do it in one query. My Mysql isn't good enough though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I was originally going to put all contacts for all accounts in the same table, but thought it would be better organized to separate them.

Comment: In general, it would be better to have all contacts in a single table, with a field that identifies the account to which they belong (accountId, for example). The difficulty you're having writing a relatively simple query is the reason this is a better model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using the following:

```
$db = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'birthday'");
$db->execute();

$month = date("m");

foreach ($db as $table) {
    $db = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT birthday 
        FROM db_contacts.$table[0] 
        WHERE MONTH(birthday) = $month;");
    $db->execute();

    foreach ($db as $record) {
        echo $record[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: bear in mind because you are not doing this on the dbms, you will be sucking in a considerable amount of data into your web server, just to see if it's the data you needed to get...